# String to Boolean in C programming language

Tags: c, string, boolean

I have a simple question. How to convert a string variable into a boleean in C?

Sample:

```
char array[] = "(1==1)";
```

How do I covert `array` into a boolean so that I can put it in `if`s?

Comment: I'm curious to know what you would need that for. Do you want to evaluate user input?

Comment: @M Oehm i have a project in school actually a big project, iwill make my own programming language in C . To make an If condition ill get the the conditions in If and make it a string and hoping to convert it in a boolean to make my job easy.

Answer (score 1):

If the string format is fixed, then you can simply pick out individual characters and subtract the ASCII value `0` from them to convert to integer. Like for example:

```
bool op1 = array[1] - '0';
bool op2 = array[4] - '0';

if(op1 == op2)
```

or if you are pedantic:

```
bool op1 = (bool)(array[1] - '0' > 0);
bool op2 = (bool)(array[4] - '0' > 0);
```

Comment: And if the string format isn't fixed, then your question is too broad.

Comment: actually the string is fixed

Comment: Is it possible to do the same when [the string isn't fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120328/always-getting-true-in-c#comment54055469_33120328)?

Comment: @CoolGuy Hmm no wonder that other question didn't make any sense, no quote marks turned it really strange. Anyway, if the string isn't fixed, you'll have to make a simple parser and divide the expression into operands and operators. The advanced version involves building up an expression tree (a form of binary tree), like a real compiler. Not a bad exercise really, but too complex to answer without any attempts by the OP to build on.