# Always getting true in C

Tags: c, boolean

Here's my simple program

```
char *array = 1==1;
if((bool)array == true)
printf("true");

Output: true
```

But when I change the array in

```
*array = 1==2;
Output: true
```

I don't know why it is always true. I just want to print if the string in variable `array` is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: this is, to say the least, very strange code. Why would you assign a bool to a `char*`?

Comment: Didn't compiler complain about anything?

Comment: can you help me pls i just want to print if the string inside the array is true or false , im just kinda experimenting on my codes

Comment: There is no string and no array here.

Comment: @karlo25 Are there any restrictions on how complicated the expression inside is? Because otherwise you would need to run a C compiler on the string at runtime.

Comment: My clang compiler refused to compile the code: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'bool'

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced. If you change the present code to `1==2` nothing gets printed, like expected.

Comment: For context, you may want to include some of what you wrote in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118130/string-to-boolean-in-c-programming-language) similar question of yours, if that is indeed what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: help me pls i need it badly , i just want to print if the condition inside my variable array is true or false , i just want to make my array variable a boolean like variable

Comment: Array = usually several values. So you want an array of booleans? C does not have booleans per say, basically zero is false and non-zero is true. So you could create an array of int for instance, each of the values would be zero (false) or !=0 (true). You can still use chars, in C a string is actually an array of 1-byte integers. So set a value of 0 at a location in the "string" and that's "false", !=0 and that's "true".

Comment: If this is related to your previous question you need to state you are trying to parse a string and evaluate an expression. Your current question is very misleading.

Comment: `char *array = 1==1;` --> `bool array = 1==1;` Better change the name `array` to something else too.

Comment: @cool guy sir but i want to print is if the string type variable is true or false not the boolean type variable helppp

Comment: @karlo25 Is the format of the string always `<number>==<number>`? Can `==` be `!=` or something else? Can `<number>` be something else?

Comment: @cool guy yes sir it can be also <char>==<char> the condition operator can also change

Comment: Could you specify what all condition operators might be there?

Comment: @cool guy all the condition operator < , > , <= , >= , == , !=

Comment: Are there any parenthesis around the data? Like `"(1==1)"`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Read they're previous SO question. They're trying to parse and evaluate expressions for a school related compiler project. This question is presented  very badly.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I know. I already did. See who edited that post.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I didn't notice that. All the answers below are going off into the weeds because of the terrible  way this is worded.

Comment: @karlo25 I'm afraid there is no easy way to do this (or maybe is impossible).

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes. I agree with you. The OP should've worded the question more better including details.

Comment: @cool guy none sir thank you for helping me , the string is like this "1==1" that's a condition but the compiler seen that as string i just want to print if there is a way if that string is true or false or you can give me a hint

Comment: @karlo25: You aren't going to learn how to write a language interpreter or compiler from a few Stack Overflow questions. Talk you your instructor for guidance.

Answer (score 6):

If you do this:

```
char *array = 1==2;
```

Then `(bool)array` **WILL** be false, like you expect, because you've just written an enormously strange way of setting the pointer 'array' to null (zero).

However, if instead, you do

```
char *array = 1==1;
*array = 1==2;
```

Then what you've done is initialised `array` to be a pointer pointing to address '1' and then written a 'false' (zero) to that address.  This will almost certainly crash your program on any modern platform, though on a small embedded platform other things (probably mostly unexpected to you) might happen.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking the pointer itself, not the thing it points to. And it so happens that you initialized the pointer to a non-zero address:

```
char *array = 1==1; // array has value 1
```

In C everything non-zero is "truthy", so a pointer with value `1` will evaluate to `true` in a boolean context.

The reason it still has a non-zero address when you do this

```
if((bool)array == true)
```

is that you never change its value after initialization. You are instead setting the value of the thing it points to here:

```
*array = 1==2; // write 0 to whatever is at address 1!
```

This does not change the value of `array` itself. It most likely causes undefined behaviour by writing to an address you shouldn't be writing to.

Answer (score 2):

The program behaviour is undefined on two counts. The first one being the cast to `bool`. That's a cast to an unrelated type. The compiler reserves the right to eat your cat.

The second one is more subtle:

`1==2` is an expression with a value 0. (Note that in C++ it is `false`.)

`1==1` is an expression with a value 1. (Note that in C++ it is `true`.)

So you are setting a pointer to point to either 0 or 1. As you don't own that memory, even *reading* the pointer value is undefined, let alone *dereferencing* it (which you're not attempting).

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array = 1==1;
if((bool)array == true)
printf("true");
```

That throws a compiler warning. Do something like this, instead:

```
int a = 0;
if ( a == true )
   {
   printf("true");
   }
else
   {
   printf("false");
   }
```

That will return `false`. Because if you do `anything == True` the comparison will be true if `anything` is literally any other value then 0